# MySQL Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Tenho uma classe `Import` (PHP) que serve para ler ficheiros XML e para inserir na BD.

Primeiramente tenho o construtor da classe `Import` que cria uma nova conexão `mysqli`:

```
...
$this->mysqli = new mysqli( HOST, USER_NAME, PASSWORD, DATA_BASE );
mysqli_set_charset( $this->mysqli, CHARSET ) or die ( "ERROR: Connection fail!" );
...
```

Na minha função de leitura (da classe `Import`) tenho este código:

```
...
$elems = $this->dom->getElementsByTagName( TAG_NAME );
foreach ( $elems as $elem )
{
   $elem1 = $elem->getElementsByTagName( TAG_ELEM1 );
   $elem2 = $elem->getElementsByTagName( TAG_ELEM2 );
   $elem3 = $elem->getElementsByTagName( TAG_ELEM3 );

   $sql2 = "SELECT `elem4` FROM `other` WHERE `elem3`=?";
   $stmt2 = $this->mysqli->prepare( $sql2 ) ; //ERRO AQUI
   $stmt2->bind_param( "i", $elem3 );
   $stmt2->execute( );
   $stmt2->bind_result($elem4);
   $stmt2->store_result( );

   $sql = "INSERT INTO `table`( `elem1`, `elem2`,  `elem4` ) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?)";
   $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare( $sql ) ;
   $stmt->bind_param( "iss", $elem1, $elem2, $elem4 );
   $stmt->execute( );
   $stmt->store_result( );
}
...
```

Ao executar tenho este erro (sinalizado no código):

> (2014) Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Já li algumas coisas em inglês e supostamente o `$stmt->store_result( );` resolveria esse erro, mas tal não acontece.

**Nota:** As tabelas estão a ser criadas antes de ser feita a leitura: `$this->mysqli->multi_query( $sql_create_all )`

Alguma ideia do que será?

Comment: `$sql` chama uma store procedure?

Comment: @perdeu editei e coloquei a query

Comment: Tinha me esquecido [desta parte](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/16290/4) que pode ser importante.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pelo que vi sobre o erro na [documentação](https://www.php.net/mysqli_query) e no [SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614671/commands-out-of-sync-you-cant-run-this-command-now), a lib `mysqli` não consegue manter dois resultados de queries (*result set*) abertos ao mesmo tempo. Cada vez que uma query é executada, é como se um cursor existisse no banco de dados apontando para a próxima linha que será lida do *result set*.

Conforme mencionado na pergunta, algumas pessoas afirmam que basta chamar o `store_result()`. Porém, lendo a [documentação](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php), parece que este método precisa ser chamado antes do `bind_result()`, principalmente se há campos `BLOB` ou `LONGTEXT` envolvidos.

Além disso, segundo [um comentário](https://www.php.net/mysqli_query#102904) da documentação, a solução é, além de fechar o *result set* com `close()`, executar um `next_result()`. Exemplo:

```php
$result = $db->query("call getUsers()");
if($result){
     // Cycle through results
    while ($row = $result->fetch_object()){
        $user_arr[] = $row;
    }
    // Free result set
    $result->close();
    $db->next_result();
}
```

---

### Atualização

Conforme mencionado em comentários, como o problema ocorre já na primeira iteração e há queries sendo executadas antes do loop, então o erro surgiu porque essas queries não estavam corretamente finalizadas. Isso porque mesmo a criação de tabelas parece retornar algum tipo de resultado, embora não entenda profundamento do MySQL para explicar o motivo.

Por isso é necessário liberar os recursos lendo todos os retornos das queries executadas usando `$result->free()` como explicando no [exemplo citado da documentação](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php#example-1746) e também em alguns comentários da documentação, conforme o exemplo citado pelo OP:

```php
while ($this->mysqli->next_result()) {
    if ($result = $this->mysqli->store_result()) {
        $result->free();
    }
}
```

Comment: Não resolveu, o problema fica exatamente o mesmo. Mas obrigado

Comment: @JorgeB. Hum... você já pensou em usar o método `query` ao invés do `execute`/`bind_result`?

Comment: porque preciso prevenir contra sql injection, nunca se sabe o que vem no XML... Já agora com query funciona direito :/

Comment: Ah e ocorre logo na primeira iteração.

Comment: @JorgeB. Não tem alguma query sendo executada antes do loop?

Comment: Tem as de criação das tabelas, eu pus ali como nota.

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema, era isso mesmo. Tinha a criação das tabelas com `multi_query`, e tinha de fazer o seguinte após a criação das tabelas: 
`while ($this->mysqli->next_result())
   if ($result = $this->mysqli->store_result()) 
 $result->free();` 
Fiz edit na pergunta, podias fazer um edit na resposta para ficar em concordância. Fonte: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php#example-1746

Comment: @JorgeB. Legal! Completei a resposta com as informações para deixar a resposta útil para quem acessar o site depois. ;)

Answer (score -3):

Este erro é devido a comandos pendentes de commit no banco.
Geralmente é bom usar a conexao e fecha-la logo em seguida.