# Problema com conexão MySql e php

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tentando fazer conexão com o banco para retirar dados que são retornados com a função get_dados_producao_graficos(), porém quando o for está na primeira interação executa normalmente, na segunda está dando:
`Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\hortsustentasp.eco.br\_conexoes_graficos\envia.php on line 35` ,ou seja, esta caindo no `if($resultados === FALSE)`.

Não faço ideia do motivo para isso ocorrer e ainda mais só na segunda interação. Existe algum erro no código?

Os valores dados as variáveis foram pensados para todas as chamadas a função irá retornar dados.

```
    $subCultura_id=5;
    $cidade=array(2,1);
    $ano=2000;
    $ano2=2015;
    $fonte=2;
    $tipo=6;

    include("../conecta.php");

    $culturas=array();
    echo "tamanho:".count($cidade);
    for($i=0;$i<count($cidade);$i++){

     echo "<br>i: ".$i."<br>";

     $query="CALL get_dados_producao_graficos({$tipo},{$cidade[$i]},{$ano}                                                  {$ano2},{$subCultura_id},{$fonte});";

     echo $query."<br><br>";

     $resultados = mysqli_query($conexao,$query);

     if($resultados === FALSE) { 
       die(mysqli_error());
     }

     while($resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultados)){

       if($resultado['valor'] > 0){
         array_push($culturas,$resultado);
       }
     }

    }
```

Resultado da execução:

```
    tamanho:2
    i: 0
    CALL get_dados_producao_graficos(6,2,2000,2015,5,2);


    i: 1
    CALL get_dados_producao_graficos(6,1,2000,2015,5,2);


    Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in         C:\xampp\htdocs\hortsustentasp.eco.br\_conexoes_graficos\envia.php on line 35
```

Comment: Sua consulta falhou, e a função `mysqli_error()` tem um parâmetro obrigatorio que é a conexão, deixe assim `mysqli_error($conexao)`

Comment: Alterei a ordem dos argumentos mas não solucionou, a primeira interação também deu o mesmo erro com isso e este erro: `Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\hortsustentasp.eco.br\_conexoes_graficos\envia.php on line 31`

Comment: Nâo mexa no `mysqli_query()` só no `mysqli_error()` ele vai retornar a mensagem de erro do banco.

Comment: Alterei o myqli_error() e retornou: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now. Achei no manual do MySql que a função `mysql_free_result($resultados);` mas não funcionou.

Comment: Ai blz, agora já tem o real problema. Pela mensagem parece que vc rodou duas ou mais consultas e não sinalizou o fim delas, SP são meio chatas ... vc não pode mandar duas consultas juntas, tem que fazer uma fechar/armazenar o resultado e ai sim fazer a proxima.

Comment: Existe algum outro jeito de fazer sem fechar e abrir a cada interação?

Comment: Tem sim to montando uma resposta aqui e testando é claro xD

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: Perdão pelo equivoco, eu havia interpretado o manual de forma errônea, os argumentos estão corretos :/

Comment: Sem problemas, obrigado pela iniciativa.

Comment: Isso aqui resolve o problema: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16309/91

Comment: Obrigado, você saberia me dizer o que causa esse erro?

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado novamente.