# Query de call no php trava outras queries

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

Porque ao fazer uma primeira query a uma call e em seguida tentar fazer outra o php trava?
Por exemplo, executar este stored procedure simples no php

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `curtidas_sp` (
    IN `@post` INT
)  
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS c_total,
FROM curtidas 
WHERE id_post = `@post`$$

DELIMITER ;
```

executando no php:

```
$f_dados = mysqli_query($conexao, "CALL curtidas_sp('$idPost')");
$f_resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($f_dados);
```

E depois tentar executar mais abaixo outro sendo ou não uma call

```
$c_dados = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS f_total, FROM favoritos WHERE id_post = 2");
$c_resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($c_dados);
```

Apresenta este erro:

**mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given...**

MariaDB, InnoDB, PHP7, Stored Procedure.

Comment: Veja o que sai em `mysqli_error($conexao)`, depois de executar cada um dos `mysqli_query`.

Comment: depois da segunda query: Comandos fora de sincronia; você não pode executar este comando agora

Comment: Experimente `mysqli_store_result($conexao); mysqli_free_result()` após a 1a query

Comment: O erro persiste do mesmo jeito

Comment: Só funciona se eu fizer assim: mysqli_close($conexao); include "dbconexao.php"; mas acho que é errado...

Comment: Veja esta outra pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16290/mysql-commands-out-of-sync-you-cant-run-this-command-now